# Unable to set CommandTimeout Value

Tags: sql, vba, adodb, oledbconnection

Can't seem to set the commandtimeout to be '1 second'. Have looked everywhere cant seem to figure it out.
Can anyone offer some help? Here is my immediate window as well:

```
Jet OLEDB:ODBC Command Time Out            1 
01             8 
05             9 
True
00             10 
00             11 
True
00             12 
00             13 
True



Sub Test()
 Dim x As Date
Dim i As Integer
x = Now

Dim objConnection As ADODB.Connection
Dim objRecordSet As ADODB.Recordset
Dim objCommand As ADODB.Command

Set objConnection = New ADODB.Connection
Set objRecordSet = New ADODB.Recordset
Set objCommand = New ADODB.Command

objConnection.CommandTimeout = 1
objConnection.Open _
    "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " & _
        "Data Source = " & sDatabaseLocation


objConnection.Properties.Item(76).Value = 1
Debug.Print objConnection.Properties.Item(76).Name, objConnection.Properties.Item(76).Value
objConnection.CommandTimeout = 1
objCommand.CommandTimeout = 1

objCommand.CommandText = squery
objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection

Debug.Print Format(Now - x, "ss"), 8: x = Now
Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute
Debug.Print Format(Now - x, "ss"), 9: x = Now
Debug.Print objRecordSet.EOF
objRecordSet.Close

Debug.Print Format(Now - x, "ss"), 10: x = Now
Set objRecordSet = objConnection.Execute(squery)
Debug.Print Format(Now - x, "ss"), 11: x = Now
Debug.Print objRecordSet.EOF
objRecordSet.Close

Debug.Print Format(Now - x, "ss"), 12: x = Now
objRecordSet.Open (squery)
Debug.Print Format(Now - x, "ss"), 13: x = Now
Debug.Print objRecordSet.EOF

 objRecordSet.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: My guess is JET doesn't support it.  In the ADO docs, it says: *Make sure the provider and data source to which you are writing code support the CommandTimeout functionality.*